# Boxplots grouped by group value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example data frame:

```
Parameter<-c("As","Hg","Pb")
Loc1<-c("1","10","12")
Loc2<-c("3","14","9")  
Loc3<-c("5","12","8")
Loc4<-c("9","20","6")
x<-data.frame(Parameter,Loc1,Loc2,Loc3,Loc4)
x$Loc1<-as.numeric(x$Loc1)
x$Loc2<-as.numeric(x$Loc2)
x$Loc3<-as.numeric(x$Loc3)
x$Loc4<-as.numeric(x$Loc4)
```

The Parameter column holds the names of the heavy metal and Loc1 to Loc4 columns hold the measured value of the heavy metal at the individual location.

I need a plot with one boxplot for each heavy metal at each location. The location is the grouping value. I tried the following:

```
melt<-melt(x, id=c("Parameter"))
ggplot(melt)+
  geom_boxplot (aes(x=Parameter, y=value, colour=variable))
```

However, the resulting plot did not somehow grouped the boxplots by location.

Comment: How do you want to draw a boxplot with just one observation per `Parameter` per `Location`? Are you perhaps after a barplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A *boxplot* with one observation per `Parameter` per `Location` makes little sense (see my example at the end of my post). I assume you are in fact after a *barplot*.**

You can do something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
    gather(Location, Value, -Parameter) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Parameter, y = Value, fill = Location)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Or with dodged bars

```
x %>%
    gather(Location, Value, -Parameter) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Parameter, y = Value, fill = Location)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

---

To demonstrate *why* a boxplot makes little sense, let's show the plot

```
x %>%
    gather(Location, Value, -Parameter) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Parameter, y = Value, colour = Location)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Note that a single observation per group results in the *bar* being reduced to a single *horizontal line*. This is probably not what you want to show.

Comment: Oh my god, I am sorry, but I somehow had the word boxplot in my head and I actually meant barplot. Three hours wasted just because of this confusion. I will blame it on Monday.

Comment: No worries @Matt. Been there as well. Tuesday after usually better;-)

Comment: @MauritsEvers try `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()` in that case ;)